# how to convert the recursion java script logic to typescript/ angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have the below javascript recursion logic where i want to implement the same in the angular

```
var dictionary = {
    'Key1': '1',
    'Key2': {
        'a' : '2',
        'b' : '3',
        'c' : {
            'd' : '3',
            'e' : '1'
        }
    }
}
function flattenDictionary(dictionary) {
    var flattenedDictionary = {};

    function flattenDitionaryHelper(dictionary, propName) {
        if (typeof dictionary != 'object') {
            flattenedDictionary[propName] = dictionary;
            return;
        }
        for (var prop in dictionary) {
            if (propName == ''){
                flattenDitionaryHelper(dictionary[prop], propName+prop);
            } else {
                flattenDitionaryHelper(dictionary[prop], propName+'.'+prop);
            }
        }
    }

    flattenDitionaryHelper(dictionary, '');
    return flattenedDictionary;
}
flattenDictionary(dictionary);
```

what i did was

```
public flatStruct(struc) {
   this.flatDictionary = {};


   let propName;
   let description;
   if(typeof struc != 'object'){
     this.flatDictionary[propName] = struc;
     console.log(this.flatDictionary);
   }
   for(var prop in struc){
     if(propName=''){
       description = struc[prop];
       console.log(description);

     }
   }


}

ngOnInit() {

  this.flatStruct(this.dict);

}
```

but  i stuck some where and i unable to get the console log also in the first attempt i am able to get the initial log later i i unable to get the data

Comment: You can directly write that code in Typescript and it will work as Typescript is Superset of JavaScript.

Comment: @PraveenOjha i just want do it in the angular way and want to check the result in logs

Comment: in typescript i cant mention as function <name>{} right and in javascript i know i am still in newbie in angular so dont know much how to apply this in angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. In TypeScript you can separate those nested functions by calling methods instead via `this`.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private flattenedDictionary = {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.go();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {}


  private go(): void {
    const dictionary = {
      'Key1': '1', 'Key2': {
        'a': '2', 'b': '3', 'c': {
          'd': '3', 'e': '1'
        }
      }
    };

    this.flattenDictionary(dictionary);

    console.log(this.flattenedDictionary);
  }

  flattenDictionary(dictionary): any {
    this.flattenDictionaryHelper(dictionary, '');
  }

  flattenDictionaryHelper(dictionary, propName): void {
    if (typeof dictionary !== 'object') {
      this.flattenedDictionary[propName] = dictionary;
      return;
    }
    for (const prop in dictionary) {
      if (propName === '') {
        this.flattenDictionaryHelper(dictionary[prop], propName + prop);
      } else {
        this.flattenDictionaryHelper(dictionary[prop], propName + '.' + prop);
      }
    }
  }
}
```